# 3.3V @ 10mA to 5V @ 50-60mA

Tags: relay, bjt, buffer, teensy

I'm trying to drive this [JBtek 4 Channel DC 5V Relay](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KTEN3TM) with a signal originating from a [teensy 3.6](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/techspecs.html). This means I somehow need to turn 3.3V @ 10 mA to 5V @ 60mA. I have a high wattage 5VDC PSU I would use, I just need a simple IC or circuit that can take my dinky signal and turn it into a less dinky signal that can drive the optocoupler on this relay board.

So far, I looked into these things which did not seem to help:

- A simple BJT circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiFumx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 83.3 Ohms is my over-approximation of the impedance of the relay input. I figure if I put the relay input at the collector of the BJT, it will always see 5V. Well since I'm here, this doesn't work because the CE voltage is always like 2.3V so inputs never see 5V.

- [Logic Converters](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bi-directional-logic-level-converter-hookup-guide) (can't supply enough current)
- a [buffer](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hct125.pdf) (also can't supply enough current, but maybe there's one out there that can?)
- a [shift register](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT595.pdf) (also can't supply enough current)
- recent epiphany on the simple BJT circuit: Any reason why I can't just be a smart and put the relay input & "ground" in series with 5V supply and BJT collector like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQLWr1.png)</sup>

By looking at an Amazon listing, I have found a possible solution to help me with my project: [image]

Is there a better way to drive these relays?

Comment: I edited your question to be less silly and something that didn't make it sound like you wanted our opinion.

Comment: Circuit 1 won't work, circuit 2 is fine. What is the actual question?

Comment: When I first started writing it, I thought it was going to be a "which IC will fix my problem" sort of a question, but then of course the super simple transistor circuit was the obvious solution. I just derp'd putting the input at the emitter instead of the collector when figuring out a circuit at first and it sent me on a weird path looking for IC solutions to a simple problem.

Comment: But who knows, this post may help some other poor fool who has the same odd question.

Answer (score 2):

According to your link, and the comments therein, this is all you need.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmJinf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

Or you can get away with a [74LVC07A](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/74LVC07A-D.PDF) if you need to drive all four relays on the board.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, schematic, and proposed IC. I'm particularly glad you posted the schematic, as I under the impression that I needed to supply current at the inputs, not drain as you have it. I probably would have put 5V right at the both Vcc and the inputs and put GND at the collector of the BJT circuit. In retrospect, I don't know how I would control each of the 4 channels that way. How did you know that it would be draining current from the inputs instead of the other way around?

Comment: @Floppydisk337 just from reading the reviews.. especially this one https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/RUNBAXRMMUMBL/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00KTEN3TM The relay schematic is also posted in there. https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2CX0NL0UBDU9T/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00KTEN3TM